# How can I repair a Whirlpool top load washer that leaks during the spin cycles?

Tags: clothes-washer

From bottom middle front. Continues dripping water after it stops and the tub is empty. Totally saturates 3 thick large bath towels.

Comment: Your posting seems like a statement. Some question about what to do for fixing the leak is just implied.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. Found that on top of tub drain holes where clogged with lint and grime. Some water spills on top while filling and splashes up when washing. Then because holes are clogged, water runs to front and over a section designed to shed water at front so as not to spill over back where electrics are. Cleaned gunk out and poked small screwdriver through holes and no more leaks. Hope this helps.
Mick.